# Servlet Request Parameter return null

Tags: java, servlets

My code is as follows:

```
<c:forEach items="${cashInList}" var="list" varStatus="stat">
   <tr> 
      <td>${list.dateandtime}
      </td>
      <td><fmt:formatNumber type="number" pattern="###,###,###,##0.00"   value="${list.cashAmount}" />
      </td>
      <td>  
         <input id="checkBoxID" type="checkbox" name="checkBoxValues" value="${list.checkBoxValue}"  />
         ${list.checkBoxValue}
      </td>
   </tr>                 
</c:forEach>
```

in the controller bean

```
String[]  checkedValues = req.getParameterValues("checkBoxValues");
```

However I got a null value.

Comment: where is your form and servlet code?

Comment: have you tried, req.getParameter("checkBoxValues");

Comment: i've already tried
it was null.
i think the request doesn't know the checkbox

Answer (score 1):

When an HTML page is submitted, no parameters are sent on the HTTP request for inputs of type "checkbox" if they are not checked.

Try a simple sample with a static HTMl page containing a simple form with two checkboxes, one checked and the other one not checked. In the development tools of your browser you should see that only a parameter for one input is added on the request.

There is also a problem in your code, you have several inputs with the same ID. You should have a different ID for each checkbox.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
As your answer, I should have a different ID for each checkbox.
But checkbox will be created according to the list data from the database.
How can I have different for this condition. I don't know the size of list and it's dynamic. not the static checkbox.

Comment: You may use the database ID as the ID of the HTML element with a prefix.

Comment: if so , how can i get the value from the request?. 
req.getParameterValues("DBID")???
It's only accepted String